# I am looking for cli for deploying cloud run with sidecar

Tags: google-cloud-run

Is there a gcloud command line for deploying service with sidecar? I only found deploying with yaml https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#multicontainer-yaml.

I am looking for something like https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#command-line

Thanks!